# Search as you type in Finder

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, search

I was on Windows few years back, and in that I could search any file or folder by typing out it's name inside Windows explorer. But I don't find a similar functionality in Finder on Mac. What I mean is that once I am inside a folder which has lots of files, I want to search for a specific file by typing its name. For e.g. if I want to search for a file named `hello.png`, I will type `h`, and then Finder will highlight the first file starting with `h`. But if I immediately type `e` after that, Finder then highlights the first file starting with `e`, and not `he`. So is it possible to search this way in Finder?

I know that I can simply type the file name in Spotlight and I will find it, but this does not work when selecting a file from browser. For e.g. when you want to upload some file, a Finder dialogue opens wherein you have to select one file. Here, a 'search as you type' feature will be very handy.

EDIT: Updating my OS to 11.1 somehow fixed this issue. But thanks to all those who helped to review this!

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand what you're indicating now.  Even in Windows I never just started typing, I always clicked in the search bar first.  I continued doing that on my Mac.  I'm deleting my comments.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated to 11.1 today, and it's working as expected now. But somehow it wasn't working this way until yesterday. So maybe this was a recent fix? 
And sorry for the confusion guys, I should have checked once again today after updating my OS.

Answer (score 4):

You're not typing fast enough.

It only waits maybe half a second, maximum, before discarding your 'h' request then starting over with your 'e'.

Here's a gif to demonstrate. If you watch the keyboard you can see what's being typed & what it selects.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. Didn't know you can search like that!

Comment: I'm working on a gif to demonstrate… few mins...

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks for your answer. However, updating my OS somehow fixed this issue. I will close this question.

Comment: You can't delete it now it has an answer - aside from that, it's still going to be useful to future searchers. We already got two people who didn't know you could do this ;))